# Having the Model in a separate project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I'm wondering if there could be any issue if I don't use the "Models" folder that the guidance created for me, but I use a separate Class Library project for the models.

From my perspective it should work, and I don't need to do anything else than adding the project since I already have it from a desktop app I made in the past. But I wanted to confirm what could be the cons of doing it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[People](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/04/07/mvc-storefront-part-1) do this all the time. If your domain model is extensive or you need to separate/isolate for large development teams or big codebases then go ahead. There's stacks of reasons not to put the Model in the Model folder. It's just a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the model in the Models folder is a convention, but it is a convention that nothing is relying on, so you can safely place your models anywhere you like.